# How to install Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

How do I download and install Apache Cassandra?

Comment: Have you try something ? For example the documentation of Cassandra : https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/getting_started/installing.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you've already done this, but here's the Apache Cassandra download page: https://cassandra.apache.org/_/download.html

Following the links to download the current GA release should put an Apache Cassandra tarball in your `~/Downloads` directory.  I'd recommend moving that:

```
cd ~
mv ~/Downloads/apache-cassandra-4.0.6-bin.tar.gz .
```

Next, untar it:

```
tar -zxvf apache-cassandra-4.0.6-bin.tar.gz
```

That will create a directory containing Apache Cassandra.  To start Cassandra `cd` into that directory and execute the `cassandra` binary.

```
cd apache-cassandra-4.0.6
bin/cassandra -p cassandra.pid
```

You should see several messages, but this indicates a successful start:

```
StorageService.java:2785 - Node localhost/127.0.0.1:7000 state jump to NORMAL
```

Running Cassandra like this with the `-p` option will put the process ID into the `cassandra.pid` file and run it in the background.  To stop Cassandra, simply run a `kill` on the contents of the file.

```
kill `cat cassandra.pid`
```

> Powershell script execution unavailable. Please use 'powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted' on this user-account to run cassandra with fully featured functionality on this platform. Starting with legacy startup options JAVA_HOME environment variable must be set!

Ahh...  You're trying to run Cassandra on Windows!  That's an important detail to mention.  Cassandra *used to* ship with Powershell scripts for this purpose...which were removed with version 4.0.  Your options:

- Run Apache Cassandra 3.11, which still has the Powershell scripts.
- Run Apache Cassandra 4.0 using local virtualization/containerization.

Last year I posted a video on how run Cassandra 4.0 locally on Windows using Minikube: [Setting up Cassandra 4.0 locally on a Windows Machine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eMKXiItZ0Q4)

You can also use the official [Cassandra container image on Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra), assuming your company allows it, and you don't mind it missing important things like security.

Comment: i open the cmd go to cassandra bin directory but after that i don't understand what to do next? can you please tell me?

Comment: Have you execute ```cassandra``` in bin directory ?

Comment: i execute command start cassandra in cmd then its open another cmd were its showing....                                                                                                                         WARNING! Powershell script execution unavailable.
   Please use 'powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted'
   on this user-account to run cassandra with fully featured
   functionality on this platform.
Starting with legacy startup options
JAVA_HOME environment variable must be set!
Press any key to continue . . .